# WordPress Comment Image plugin doesn't save uploaded image when Apache Requires are used

Tags: wordpress, apache, upload, requires

I've got an Apache 2.4.7 box with a WordPress 4.1 installation and a plugin added which allows users to add images to comments on pages/posts (https://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-images/). The image upload feature isn't working when `Require` statements are added to restrict access to the site (it's a development environment so limited access is required).

The image upload actually **works with or without** `Require` directives **but** when the directives are added, the reference to the uploaded image doesn't get saved to WordPress properly.

The error from the log is:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/comment-images/class-comment-image.php on line 480
```

I dumped the object being passed into a file (serialized):

```
O:8:"WP_Error":2:{s:16:"^@WP_Error^@errors";a:1:{s:8:"http_404";a:1:{i:0;s:12:"Unauthorized";}}s:20:"^@WP_Error^@error_data";a:0:{}}
```

I outputted the `print_debug_backtrace()` as well to show the calls. I've had to delete the comment data from the arrays for privacy reasons:

```
#0  Comment_Image->save_comment_image(63)
#1  call_user_func_array(Array ([0] => Comment_Image Object ([] => 5000000,[] => ,[] => ),[1] => save_comment_image), Array ([0] => 63)) called at [/var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:496]
#2  do_action(wp_insert_comment, 63, stdClass Object ()) called at [/var/www/html/wp-includes/comment.php:1941]
#3  wp_insert_comment(Array ()) called at [/var/www/html/wp-includes/comment.php:2083]
#4  wp_new_comment(Array ()) called at [/var/www/html/wp-comments-post.php:137]
```

The directives for the `<Directory>` with the WP install in are (with IPs obfuscated):

```
AllowOverride All
<RequireAny>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Access"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    Require user dev www-data
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx/xx
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
    Require local
</RequireAny>
```

If I add `Require all granted` (or just remove the `Require` directives), then the feature works as expected and uploaded images show up. Note `Require local` is there which as I understand it should cover everything for the local box.

Things I've checked:

- Revised the configs in light of Apache 2.4 changes to auth modules and ordering importance etc.
- WordPress install folder is recursively chown'ed correctly
- Permissions on upload folder are 777'd, but shouldn't matter as the upload always succeeds

Where does this issue lie??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the plugin does not handle well the fact that your server is unable to download an image on itself.

The warning (`class-comment-image.php on line 480`) corresponds to this snippet:

```
$img_url = media_sideload_image( $comment_image_file['url'], $post_id );

preg_match_all( "#[^<img src='](.*)[^'alt='' />]#", $img_url, $matches );

$comment_image_file['url'] = $matches[0][0];
```

The WP `media_sideload_image` function uses curl to get the image, and because of your restrictions it does not succeed, and then returns an error object that the `preg_match_all` function cannot handle.

The data is saved later in the metas; it explains why the reference is not saved even if the upload worked.

`Require local` probably does not work on your dev server, you may try to replace it with its local address.

Comment: I have tried adding Require ip <local-ip-of-box> and didn't doesn't work. This line of thinking has however led me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `Require ip <local-ip-of-box>` as per johansatge's suggestion. Whilst this didn't doesn't work, it made me think..

The box is in Azure which assigns a floating public IP. Annoyingly, the cURL request was bouncing out and using that public IP - because the domain used for the box wasn't added to the hosts file.

The solution was to add `<domain-of-website-on-box>` to the loopback (127.0.0.1) entry in `/etc/hosts`.